# Ruta reporte Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Estoy haciendo una aplicación `ASP.NET` en `C#` y tengo un reporte en `Crystal Report` grabado en un directorio donde está la aplicación:
`aplicación\bin\reportes\CR.rpt`

Cuando trato de darle la ruta al reporte me arroja error de no encontrar el archivo, y ya he intentado todas las posibles variantes del LOAD

```
CrRpt.Load(@"reportes\CR.rpt");
CrRpt.Load(@"reportes/CR.rpt");
CrRpt.Load(@"\reportes\CR.rpt"); etc
```

donde `CrRpt` es el `ReportDocument` de Crystal

Podrá alguien indicarme cual podría ser el problema

Answer (score -1):

Debes de darle la ruta del aplicación es decir:

```
CrRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\reportes\CR.rpt");
```

StartupPath obtiene la ruta de ejecución de la aplicación